# Audio File Encoding and Decoding

Tags: java, android, audio, encoding, base64

What is the efficient way to encode and decode an audio file in android
I have tried the Base64 as below but after decoding the file size get increased. 
**Encode**

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream objByteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        File file = new File(path);
        FileInputStream objFileIS;
        try {
            objFileIS = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] byteBufferString = new byte[1024];

        for (int readNum; (readNum = objFileIS.read(byteBufferString)) != -1;) {
            objByteArrayOS.write(byteBufferString, 0, readNum);
            System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
            byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);


            strAttachmentCoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,
                    Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**Decode**

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(strAttachmentCoded,
                    Base64.DEFAULT);
            // byte[] decoded1 = Base64.decode(byteBinaryData1, 0);
            File file1 = new File(pathAudio);

            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file1, true);
            os.write(decoded);

            os.close();
```

i want audio in String format to send to server and retrieve the same as per the user requirement.

Comment: Why do you want to encode/decode? And yes, Base64 will always increase the size of its input, by design.

Comment: Why does it have to be sent as a `String`?

Comment: @fge --encoding is required because i need send the audio file to the server and decoding is required when i receive any audio file from server for playing perpose.

Comment: You might as well not use encoding at all!

Comment: @Squonk Decode the the audio file to byte array is also fine but has same issue, that the audio file size getting increased.

Comment: @fge then how will I send the audio to sever????

Comment: Well, just send it as is! Where is the problem with that?

Comment: @fge --i think u r right and i will send the file as it is to the server...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[wikipedia:base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) ([rfc3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548)) is the right method to choose I would think. It is most common now I think having taken over from [wikipedia:uuencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding).

To answer the question . . .

1. You could add some padding. The [wikipedia article on base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) gives a good example of padding.
2. Or you could add a header to your audio string including length. The header could also include other control data so it may be something you want to include anyway.