# Android Base64 Audio File Encode and Decode

Tags: android, base64, android-mediaplayer

**What I am doing:**  I am currently recording voice and saving it as a file in SDCard which is running / playing fine in MediaPlayer.

**What I want:** When I encode this file intoBase64 and send to server, everything goes fine. But When i decode the Base64 String into audio.m4a file, it is not running in MediaPlayer.

I had tried **.m4a** , **.wav** but all in vain.
The problem is in encoding. Because when I decode a file sent from the same iOS app, it runs fine in MediaPlayer.

I know its very basic and alot of help is there to encode decode but nothing is working. Following is my approach:

```
 private void encodeAudio(String selectedPath) {

    byte[] audioBytes;
    try {

        // Just to check file size.. Its is correct i-e; Not Zero
        File audioFile = new File(selectedPath);
        long fileSize = audioFile.length();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath));
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
            baos.write(buf, 0, n);
        audioBytes = baos.toByteArray();

        // Here goes the Base64 string
        _audioBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(audioBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        DiagnosticHelper.writeException(e);
    }

}
```

**And Decoding in the following way:**

```
private void decodeAudio(String base64AudioData, File fileName, String path, MediaPlayer mp) {

    try {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.write(Base64.decode(base64AudioData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        fos.close();

        try {

            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setDataSource(path);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            DiagnosticHelper.writeException(e);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Please point if I am doing anything wrong/silly.

Comment: Use as prescribed in below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596345/audio-file-encoding-and-decoding

Comment: @Sumit .. i had seen this before. No use.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Multipartentity to upload any type of file to server.

public void postFile(String file_path, String url){
        File file = new File(file_path);

```
    try {
        System.out.println(file_path);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);


        FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("file", bin); /*I believe that the "file" is the name in php part*/
        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to convert into Base64 encoded string. Its a requirement.

Comment: pls try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448865/base64-encode-audio-file-and-send-as-a-string-then-decode-the-string

Comment: Have a look at my code please... Am i doing something different?
Come on... i am doing the same thing !!